# Solving the absolute value inequality $\big| \frac{x}{x + 4} \big| < 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I was given this question and asked to find $x$:
$$\left| \frac{x}{x+4} \right|<4$$

I broke this into three pieces:
$$
\left| \frac{x}{x+4} \right| = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{x}{x+4} & \quad x > 0 \\
            -\frac{x}{x+4} & \quad -4 < x < 0 \\
            \frac{x}{x+4} & \quad x < −4
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Solving,
$$4>\frac{x}{x+4}$$
$$4x+16>x$$
$$3x>-16$$
$$x>-\frac{16}{3}=-5.3$$

and
$$4>-\frac{x}{x+4}$$
$$4x+16>-x$$
$$5x>-16$$
$$x>-3.2$$

The answer is $x<-5.3$ and $x>-3.2$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By his calculus, $x>-5.3$ and $x>-3.2$. Then $x>-3.2$ is the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake was not considering the restrictions on $x$ when you solved the individual cases.

**Case 1:**  $x \geq 0$

If $x > 0$, then $x + 4 > 0$, so the direction of the inequality is preserved if we multiply by $x + 4$.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{x + 4} & <  4\\
x & < 4(x + 4)\\
x & < 4x + 16\\
-16 & < 3x\\ 
-\frac{16}{3} & < x
\end{align*}
as you found.  However, the restriction that $x \geq 0$ means $x \geq 0$ and $x > -\dfrac{16}{3} \Longrightarrow x \geq 0$.  You did not account for the restriction $x \geq 0$.

Also, note that $-\dfrac{16}{3} \approx 5.3$.  The statement you made that $-\dfrac{16}{3} = 5.3$ is false since the decimal approximation you used does not actually equal the fraction.

**Case 2:**  $-4 < x < 0$

Since $-4 < x < 0$, $x + 4 > 0$.  Thus, the direction of the inequality is preserved if we multiply both sides of the inequality by $x + 4$.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
-\frac{x}{x + 4} & < 4\\
-x & < 4(x + 4)\\
-x & < 4x + 16\\
-16 & < 5x\\
-\frac{16}{5} & < x
\end{align*}
as you found.  The restriction that $-4 < x < 0$ means $-4 < x < 0$ and $-\dfrac{16}{5} < x \Longrightarrow -\dfrac{16}{5} < x < 0$.  You did not account for the restriction $x < 0$.

**Case 3:**  $x < -4$

If $x < -4$, then $x + 4 < 0$, so the direction of the inequality is reversed if we multiply both sides of the inequality by $x + 4$, which you did not take into account.
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{x + 4} & < 4\\
x & > 4(x + 4)\\
x & > 4x + 16\\
-16 & > 3x\\
-\frac{16}{3} & > x
\end{align*}
The restriction that $x < -4$ means that $x < -4$ and $x < -\dfrac{16}{3} \Longrightarrow x < -\dfrac{16}{3}$.

Combining the results of the three cases yields 
$$x \geq 0~\text{or}-\frac{16}{5} < x < 0~\text{or}~x < -\frac{16}{3} \Longrightarrow x > -\frac{16}{5}~\text{or}~x < -\frac{16}{3}$$
Hence, the solution set is 
$$S = \left(-\frac{16}{5}, \infty\right) \cup \left(-\infty, -\frac{16}{3}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you. Your answer included information that filled the general gaps in my knowledge. Highly edifying and neatly presented.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|\frac{x}{x+4}\right|<4$$

Squaring, you get

$$\frac{x^2}{16(x+4)^2}<1$$

Rearranging we get

$$15x^2 + 128x+256 >0$$

Using quadratic roots

$$(x+\frac{16}{5}) (x+\frac{16}{3}) >0$$

Hence  the solution is $$x \in (-\infty,-\frac{16}{3})\cup(-\frac{16}{5},\infty)$$

Comment: Use `\cup` to get "$\cup$". But anyway your notation is incorrect, because "$x > -3.2$" is a boolean statement, being either true or false, and you **cannot** union it with anything. Rather, you want to say $x \in (-\infty,-\frac{16}{3}) \cup (3.2,\infty)$.

Comment: And sorry I'm going to downvote because you rounded off without stating, and so technically the "5.33" in your answer is wrong, because if $x = -5.332$ then the inequality does not hold. If you fix that then I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @user21820, I have made the correction.  Thanks for noticing the error!!

Comment: Sure I've removed my downvote, and to get "$\in$" use `\in`. To see what LaTeX is behind any formula, you can Right-click > Show Math As > TeX commands.

Answer (score 1):

You need to analyze each case separately, and it is **always wrong** to round off in mathematics without explicitly stating that it is an approximation. Do not forget that to find the solutions you need to take into account the cases! Also, you missed the case of $x = 0$.
$\def\eq{\Leftrightarrow}$

Take any real $x \ne -4$.

If $0 \le x$:

$\left| \frac{x}{x+4} \right|<4 \eq \frac{x}{x+4} < 4 \eq x < 4x+16 \eq x > -\frac{16}{3}$.

If $-4 < x < 0$:

$\left| \frac{x}{x+4} \right|<4 \eq -\frac{x}{x+4} < 4 \eq -x < 4x+16 \eq x > -\frac{16}{5}$.

If $x < -4$:

$\left| \frac{x}{x+4} \right|<4 \eq \frac{x}{x+4} < 4 \eq x > 4x+16 \eq x < -\frac{16}{3}$.

Thus $\left| \frac{x}{x+4} \right|<4 \eq \left( 0 \le x \land x > -\frac{16}{3} \right) \lor \left( -4<x<0 \land x > -\frac{16}{5} \right) \lor \left( x<-4 \land x < -\frac{16}{3} \right)$.

Thus $\left| \frac{x}{x+4} \right|<4 \eq x \ge 0 \lor -\frac{16}{5}<x<0 \lor x<-\frac{16}{3}$.

["$\land$" means "and" and "$\lor$" means "or".]

Comment: Since $x \geq 0 \vee -\frac{16}{5} < x < 0 \Leftrightarrow x > -\frac{16}{5}$, you could write $x > -\frac{16}{5} \vee x < -\frac{16}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Case** $\#1:$  For $x+4\ne0$

As for real $y, a>0$

$$|y|<a\iff -a<y<a$$

$$\implies\left|\dfrac x{x+4}\right|<4\iff-4<\dfrac x{x+4}<4$$

Now $-4<\dfrac x{x+4}\iff0<\dfrac x{x+4}+4=\dfrac{5x+16}{x+4}=5\cdot\dfrac{(x+4)\left(x+\dfrac{16}5\right)}{(x+4)^2}$

$\iff(x+4)\left(x+\dfrac{16}5\right)>0$

Now if $(z-a)(z-b)>0$ with $a<b$ for real $z,$  either $z<a$ or $z>b$ (Prove this)

Similarly deal with $$\dfrac x{x+4}<4$$

**Case** $\#2:$ Check for $x+4=0$

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very simple. :)

Why admin delete my ANS?????????????????????

Here's my Hint:
$$\left | \dfrac{x}{x+4} \right |<4 \overset{x \ne -4}{\rightarrow} -4<\dfrac{x}{x+4}<4 \Leftrightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}
 &-4<\dfrac{x}{x+4} \\ 
 & \dfrac{x}{x+4}<4
\end{matrix}\right.
\Leftrightarrow
\left\{\begin{matrix}
 &\dfrac{5x+16}{x+4}>0 \\ 
 & \dfrac{3x+16}{x+4}>0
\end{matrix}\right.$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 
\left\{\begin{matrix}
 &x \in\left ( -\infty;-4 \right )\cup \left ( -\dfrac{16}{5};+\infty \right ) \\ 
 & x \in\left ( -\infty;-\dfrac{16}{3} \right )\cup \left ( -4;+\infty \right )
\end{matrix}\right.
\Rightarrow \boxed{x \in \left ( -\infty;-\dfrac{16}{3} \right )\cup \left ( -\dfrac{16}{5};+\infty \right).}$$

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen (mod): You said "Because the problem of needing to split the treatment into cases according to the sign of the denominator does not go away". Why do you delete my ANS? I'm sorry when I say that You don't understand math. We solve a problem with MANY different methods, why do I have to do according to your solutions. If possible, you show to me in my solutions where wrong. In my opinion, the opinion of a member of the site you should sorry me, because you arbitrarily deleted my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the interval into 3 pieces.

X is between (-4,0)

X is greater than 0

X is less than -4

On each interval try to figure out whether the sign is positive or negative.

$$\left (\frac{|x|}{|x+4|}\right)$$